# My quotes are not printing

Tags: javascript, html

## I'm not making a reference on one of the functions, can anyone explain to me what I'm missing?

So far I've created an array of quotes and now I'm trying to use them with a random generator. I want to display them on a page after I click a button.
Though I been working on it for a while and cant see where I'm making a reference on the functions.

Here is what I have so far:

---

```
    var quotes = ['quoteOne', 'quoteTwo', 'quoteThree', 'quoteFour',     'quoteFive'];
quoteOne = {
    quote : 'I meant what I said and I said what I meant.',
    source : 'Dr. Seuss',
    citation : 'dont know',
    year : '1990'
}
    quoteTwo = {
    quote : 'Truth is everybody is going to hurt you: you just gotta find the     ones worth suffering for.',
    source : 'Bob Marley',
    citation : 'Smoke session',
    year : '1989'
}
    quoteThree = {
    quote : 'Never interrupt your enemy when he is making a mistake.',
    source : 'Napoleon Bonaparte',
    citation : 'I dont know',
    year : 'N/a'
}
    quoteFour = {
    quote : 'Fear is the main source of superstition, and one of the main sources of cruelty. To conquer fear is the beginning of wisdom.',
    source : 'Bertrand Russell',
    citation : 'I dont know',
    year : 'N/a'
}
    quoteFive = {
    quote : 'Curiosity will conquer fear even more than bravery will.',
    source : 'James Stephens',
    citation : 'I dont know',
    year : 'some year'
}
function getRandomQuote() {
     var item = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random()* quotes.length)];
     for(var i=0; i<quotes.length; i++){
    var quotes = quotes[i];
    var content = '<strong class="lead" style="color:#00000;">' + quotes.name + '</strong> - (<a target="_blank" href="' + quotes.source + '">url</a>)<hr style="margin:0;"><p style="margin-bottom:0;">' + quotes.citation + '<br>' + quotes.year + ', ' ;
        document.getElementById('loadQuote').addEventListener("click",     printQuote, false);
     }
     console.log('im working');
}
    function printQuote() {
     var print = getRandomQuote();
     document.getElementById('quote-box').innerHTML
     console.log('im still working');
}
```

Comment: When you step through this in a debugger, where/how specifically does it fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Errors are here:

```js
    quoteOne = {
        quote : 'I meant what I said and I said what I meant.',
        source : 'Dr. Seuss',
        citation : 'dont know',
        year : '1990'
    }
        quoteTwo = {
        quote : 'Truth is everybody is going to hurt you: you just gotta find the     ones worth suffering for.',
        source : 'Bob Marley',
        citation : 'Smoke session',
        year : '1989'
    }
        quoteThree = {
        quote : 'Never interrupt your enemy when he is making a mistake.',
        source : 'Napoleon Bonaparte',
        citation : 'I dont know',
        year : 'N/a'
    }
        quoteFour = {
        quote : 'Fear is the main source of superstition, and one of the main sources of cruelty. To conquer fear is the beginning of wisdom.',
        source : 'Bertrand Russell',
        citation : 'I dont know',
        year : 'N/a'
    }
    quoteFive = {
        quote : 'Curiosity will conquer fear even more than bravery will.',
        source : 'James Stephens',
        citation : 'I dont know',
        year : 'some year'
    }
    var quotes = [quoteOne, quoteTwo, quoteThree, quoteFour,quoteFive];

    function getRandomQuote() {
        var item = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random()* quotes.length)];
        return '<strong class="lead" style="color:#00000;">' + item.quote + '</strong> - (<a target="_blank" href="' + item.source + '">url</a>)<hr style="margin:0;"><p style="margin-bottom:0;">' + item.citation + '<br>' + item.year + ', ' ;
    }
    function printQuote() {
        document.getElementById('quote-box').innerHTML = getRandomQuote();
    }

    console.log(printQuote());
```

```html
<div id="quote-box"></div>
```

- You get a single document using `quotes[randomNumber]`, so no need to loop,
- You didn't set the `innerHTML` to the `getRandomQuote()` value in `printQuote()`,
- There was no `return` value from `getRandomQuote()`.

Comment: now it gives me an undefined, great is working well thanks.

Comment: i added the 'click' action now is working like a clock, thanks dude much happy here.

Answer (score 1):

First at all you have to remove quotations from this array

```
var quotes = ['quoteOne', 'quoteTwo', 'quoteThree', 'quoteFour','quoteFive'];
```

Because here you are adding strings to array and not arrays. So i changed it to

```
var quotes = [quoteOne, quoteTwo, quoteThree, quoteFour,quoteFive];
```

And im alerting all quotes while iterating through this quotes array. Chech snippet

```js
quoteOne = {
    quote : 'I meant what I said and I said what I meant.',
    source : 'Dr. Seuss',
    citation : 'dont know',
    year : '1990'
}
    quoteTwo = {
    quote : 'Truth is everybody is going to hurt you: you just gotta find the     ones worth suffering for.',
    source : 'Bob Marley',
    citation : 'Smoke session',
    year : '1989'
}
    quoteThree = {
    quote : 'Never interrupt your enemy when he is making a mistake.',
    source : 'Napoleon Bonaparte',
    citation : 'I dont know',
    year : 'N/a'
}
    quoteFour = {
    quote : 'Fear is the main source of superstition, and one of the main sources of cruelty. To conquer fear is the beginning of wisdom.',
    source : 'Bertrand Russell',
    citation : 'I dont know',
    year : 'N/a'
}
    quoteFive = {
    quote : 'Curiosity will conquer fear even more than bravery will.',
    source : 'James Stephens',
    citation : 'I dont know',
    year : 'some year'
}
    var quotes = [quoteOne, quoteTwo, quoteThree, quoteFour,quoteFive];
function getRandomQuote() {
     var item = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random()* quotes.length)];
     for(var i=0; i<quotes.length; i++){
    var content = '<strong class="lead" style="color:#00000;">' + quotes[i].name + '</strong> - (<a target="_blank" href="' + quotes[i].source + '">url</a>)<hr style="margin:0;"><p style="margin-bottom:0;">' + quotes[i].citation + '<br>' + quotes[i].year + ', ' ;
       alert(content);
      document.getElementById('loadQuote').addEventListener("click",     printQuote, false);
     }
     alert('im working');
}
    function printQuote() {
     var print = getRandomQuote();
     document.getElementById('quote-box').innerHTML
     console.log('im still working');
}
printQuote();
```

```html
<div id ='loadQuote'> khk</div>
<div id = 'quote-box'> </div>
```